# Nowadays, do we write "besulah" & "200 zuz" in the ketubah for every woman's first marriage?

Tags: ketubah, maseches-kesubos

I remember once hearing that even though the mishnah & gemara in Maseches Ketubah state that a *besulah*/ virgin maiden gets 200 zuz for a ketubah (and a a *be'ulah*/non-virgin maiden gets 100 zuz)-- nevertheless so as not to embarrass the bride (ie if she were a ba'al teshuva etc),
 the practice nowadays for a first marriage is to write 200 zuz in every ketubah.

Is this true/ source?

Comment: My parents were both deaf. I'll have to check their Ketubah, again. I think their amount was different, and I'm uncertain of that's because a Cheresh may have a different status or it could be because the *Bet Din* acted as the intermediary for the Ketubah. I also am quit certain that a convert has a lower value. I'll see if my friend recalls this.

Comment: This is definitely not universally true. If the woman is forbidden to a Kohein (eg. she slept with a gentile, which is not uncommon amongst Baalot Teshuva) then it's forbidden to write Betula since if she is widowed they won't know she's forbidden to a Kohein. If she has only slept with her fiance then there's what to talk about fudging the numbers, if everyone is on board.

Comment: see also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28537/170

Comment: If in the Ketuba it's not written betula, the amount has not a sense of proof. Not sure

Comment: @kouty not necessarily true- the gemara/ SA say that one is allowed to add on as much as they like, someone could've added to make it 200

Comment: I agree. This was my intent. I added that there is no risk that someone makes it a proof she was betula because in the Ketuba the word betula is not written

Answer (score 1):

I located a [M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38550/5275) that I asked a while ago about my parents' *cherish* ketubah. See [this text](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpagefeed.aspx?req=6914&pgnum=162) for sample ketubot for *chershim* in various forms and combos. In each, you'll notice that the amount given is 100 zuz.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from personal experience, this is not universally true, but is often the case. I was recently at the wedding of a couple (already had a child) that had converted to Judaism and remarried Jewishly (first Jewish wedding), and they called her "Giyurta Da", and her kesubah sum was 100 zuz. See also DanF's answer above.

However, I heard from a local Rav that in cases where the girl had engaged in relations before she was married, but it was not publicly known, they still write 200 zuz and call her a virgin in the Kesubah, due to Kavod Haberiyos. I would assume if she was visibly pregnant or something along those lines they would not write 200 zuz.

While I don't have an explicit source for this (no access to fancy databases right now, or even a Hebrew Keyboard to google things with), Rav Shternbuch in Teshuvos Vehanhagos 1:755 talks about making Sheva Brachos meals for a couple when she was not a virgin, and allows a "beracha levatalah" so that she will not be embarrassed. See there further for a chiddush of his regarding the definition of a virgin in this regard.

Comment: Is R Shternbuch talking about not a virgin with the fiance or not a virgin more broadly

Comment: @double I don't remember, and no longer have it in front of me.
Based on his chiddush there it shouldn't matter, but I understand why people would be more strict if she wasn't a virgin with the fiance...